# Java based library for sensor data collection

Tags: java, real-time, sensors, data-stream

I'm looking for an embeddable Java library that is suitable for collecting **real-time streams of sensor data** in a general-purpose way. I plan to use this to develop a "hub" application for reporting on multiple disparate sensor streams, running on a JVM based server (will also be using Clojure for this).

Key things it needs to have:

- Interfaces for various common sensor types / APIs. I'm happy to build what I need myself, but it would be nice if some standard stuff comes out of the box.
- Suitable for "soft real time" usage, i.e. fairly low latency and low overhead.
- Ability to monitor and manage streams at runtime, gather statistics etc.
- Open source under a reasonably permissive license so that I can integrate it with other code (Apache, EPL, BSD, LGPL all fine)
- A reasonably active community / developer ecosystem

Is there something out there that fits this profile that you can recommend?

Comment: Why not just use Android?

Comment: I'll be running on the JVM - does Android provide a library that would work in this context? If so, then that might be a good answer.

Comment: You write the code in Java, but it runs on a Dalvik machine. You may want to look at this, as a starting point, and see if your requirements are going to be added to: http://www.opersys.com/downloads/cc-slides/embedded-android/embedded-android-120203.pdf

Answer (score 14):

**1. Round-robin database ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool))**

> RRDtool (acronym for round-robin database tool) aims to handle
>   time-series data like network bandwidth, temperatures, CPU load, etc.
>   The data are stored in a round-robin database (circular buffer), thus
>   the system storage footprint remains constant over time.

This approach/DB format is widely used, stable and simple enough. Out of the box it allows to generate nice plots:

[image]

There is Java implementation -- [RRD4J](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/):

> RRD4J is a high performance data logging and graphing system for time
>   series data, implementing RRDTool's functionality in Java. It follows
>   much of the same logic and uses the same data sources, archive types
>   and definitions as RRDTool does. Open Source under Apache 2.0 License.

**Update**

Forget to mention there is Clojure RRD API ([examples](https://github.com/maoe/rrd4clj/blob/master/src/clj/rrd4clj/examples.clj)).

**2. For some experiments with real-time data I would suggest to consider [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst_database_spec)**

It is small, fast and reliable enough, but distributed under GPLv3. Perst provides several indexing algorithms:

1. B-Tree
2. T-Tree (optimized for in-memory database)
3. R-Tree (spatial index)
4. Patricia Trie (prefix search)
5. KD-Tree (multidimensional index)
6. **Time series (large number of fixed size objects with timestamp)**

The last one suits your needs very well.

**3. [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org) with [Relationship indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-relationships.html)**

> A good example where this approach pays dividends is in time series
>   data, where we have readings represented as a relationship per
>   occurrence.

**4. [Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/index.html)**

> Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition is an open source, embeddable,
>   transactional storage engine written entirely in Java. It takes full
>   advantage of the Java environment to simplify development and
>   deployment. The architecture of Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition
>   supports very high performance and concurrency for both read-intensive
>   and write-intensive workloads.

**Suggestion**

Give a try to [RRD4J](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/):

1. It is simple enough
2. It dose provide quite a nice plots
3. It has Clojure API
4. It supports several back-ends including [Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/index.html)
5. It can store/visualize detailed data sets

[image]

Comment: I think you should add [http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.com/disruptor/) as he might need some message passing.

Answer (score 2):

For collecting real-time streams of sensor data following might be of help

Have you checked LeJos API's. This http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxt/nxj/api/index.html

Also it is worth checking Oracle Java ME Embedded and the target markets they are addressing http://www.unitask.com/oracledaily/2012/10/04/at-the-java-demogrounds-oracle-java-me-embedded-enables-the-internet-of-things/

Can be downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javame/index.html

For storing the Time series data nothing beats cassandra http://cassandra.apache.org/ and to answer why cassandra refer http://www.datastax.com/why-cassandra

For accessing Cassandra from Java refer https://github.com/jmctee/Cassandra-Client-Tutorial 
It is quite helpful and applying the time series concept in cassandra db refer
http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/C2012-ColumnsandEnoughTime-JohnAkred.pdf